# Choosing behaviour based on object type: the object-oriented way?

Tags: oop

### First problem:

I have a `Server` class, a `Message` abstract base class and many message types `MessageType1`, `MessageType2` etc. that derive from `Message`. The server recieves a `Message` and begins to process it. Now, how do I make appropriate behaviour happen and how do I go about it the object-oriented way? I understand that getting the type and using a `switch` is not the solution.

### Second problem:

I feel it has much in common with the first. I have a base `Object` class and many object types deriving from it. The objects "fly" randomly in an imaginary space and any type can "run into" the other. For each different type pair of such encounter, I would like different behaviour defined that affects both objects. How do I go about it the object-oriented way?

Comment: This question is pretty broad. To me it seems pretty close to "teach me the basics of object-oriented design." Please elaborate on a specific question you have, and what you've tried.

Comment: I agree that the second problem is quite broad, but the first one is an actual problem I'm encountering now in a C# app. I thought about adding a `Process()` method to `Message` and override it with specific behaviour, but processing the message includes deep interaction with the server, and passing the server instance as an argument seems like... forcing it?

Comment: Then elaborate on the second part. There's hardly any detail. Show some code that you've tried. Something.